# please give the reason why every notation for DFT is valid?

Tags: dft

$X$ represents sample in frequency domain and $x$ represents samples in time domain.

**NOTATION 1**

$ X[k] = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] \ e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N} n k} $

$ x[n] = \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] \ e^{j \frac{2\pi}{N} n k} $

**NOTATION 2**

$ X[k] = \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] \ e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N} n k} $

$ x[n] = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] \ e^{j \frac{2\pi}{N} n k} $

**NOTATION 3**

$ X[k] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] \ e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N} n k} $

$ x[n] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] \ e^{j \frac{2\pi}{N} n k} $

**NOTATION 4**

$ X[k] = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] \ e^{j \frac{2\pi}{N} n k} $

$ x[n] = \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] \ e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N} n k} $

Please observe the scaling factor $\frac{1}{N}$ and change of a negative sign $-$ over the exponent term ${e^{\pm j\frac{{2\pi }}{N}nk} }$. Why is every notation of DFT valid?

Comment: Who told you they are all valid definitions?

Comment: I have seen the above notations in some research papers (IEEE letters & transactions on wireless, signal processing). Please could you explain why the above notations are not valid for DFT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply does not matter and it is just a matter of convention which version is used. I always use the first definition, which is also the one you will find in (almost) all textbooks on DSP. If you take always the same time domain signal $x[n]$ then it is obvious that $X_2[k]$ (according to notation 2) and $X_3[k]$ (according to notation 3) are simply scaled versions of $X[k]$ (according to notation 1). The one with scaling $1/\sqrt{N}$ is the *unitary* version of the DFT (i.e. the DFT becomes a unitary transformation). It's just notation number 4 that is a bit weird. In this case, $X_4[k]=X[-k]$, but I have never seen the sign convention like this. In this case, $x[n]$ can be interpreted as the Fourier series coefficients of $X[k]$. But again, all four versions are OK and you're free to use any of them as long as everybody knows which version of the DFT you mean.

Answer (score 0):

likewise to @MattL.'s answer, just observe that $x[n]$ in **NOTATION 2** is scaled to be $N$ times larger than the $x[n]$ in **NOTATION 1**.  and $x[n]$ in **NOTATION 3** is scaled to be $\sqrt{N}$ times larger than the $x[n]$ in **NOTATION 1**.  that's all that change of convention means.

in **NOTATION 4**, just note that there is **no** operational difference between $-j$ and $+j$.  both numbers are purely imaginary and they both have equal claim to squaring to be $-1$ or have equal claim to being the $\sqrt{-1}$ (stating it loosely).  these two numbers are not ***equal***, but they *are* **equivalent**.  they have identical properties (which are simply that they are not real numbers and they square to be $-1$).

so as long as all occurrences of $j$ are replaced by $-j$ (which means that all occurances of $-j$ are replaced by $+j$) in **all** of the theorems that come with the DFT, then **NOTATION 4** will be fine as a convention and is just as valid as **NOTATION 1**.

in both cases, the scaling case and the case of swapping of $-j$ and $+j$, note that the theorems associated with the DFT must also be modified slightly for them to be "equally valid" conventions.

Comment: Although Notation 4 isn't quite the normal, you can relate it to the other definitions by letting $m=-n$ and then rewriting the equation. Essentially it swaps what are normally the time domain and the frequency domain.

You can also show that the DFT(DFT(x(n)))=x(-n). That is, if you take the DFT of the DFT  you end up with a time reversed sequence.